# Should questions stop providing reputation after a certain time period?

Tags: discussion, reputation

So i've been wondering if residual reputation is a bad thing for stack overflow?

Take my profile as an example - I've hardly been active in the last couple of years - yet I'm constantly in the top 2% of users/year purely because I asked a bunch of questions in my early days on stack overflow.

[image: Residual reputation]

What i'm concerned about is that pretty soon i'll have access to the moderation tools - when I'm no longer putting in the effort to earn the privilege. While i'm not planning on abusing them obviously what is to stop another user in the same boat doing the same thing?

So my basic question is - should residual income from a question stop after a time period?

Comment: Are you intending to specifically emphasize questions?  I know [a user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/179736/timex) who has received a ton of rep from questions and based on some [recent questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30360096/2792531), he is not ready for *any* site moderation/editing privilidges.

Comment: Commit them to community then, if you're feeling bad gaining reputation from them.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not possible to convert questions to CW without also affecting all answers.

Comment: What time period would it be? And would it affect only questions or answers too?

Comment: Cross site duplicate: [Should there be an upper rep gain limit for answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6823/should-there-be-an-upper-rep-gain-limit-for-answers)

Comment: _I've hardly been active in the last couple of years_ - Rather than limit reputation then, maybe tie access to moderation tools to recent activity. So instead of only requiring 20K in rep, you also have to have been active on the site X% of the time in the last N days with your actions being well-received.

Comment: Perhaps reputation and/or privileges should decay over time if the user is not active. Eg if no log on in X days then reduce reputation by Y%. (Where X is at least 30 and could be 100.) Perhaps there could be two measures of reputation, **total** which is just the same as now and **effective** which decreases (decays) when the user is inactive. Privileges would be based on the **effective** reputation.

Comment: I quite like the effective vs total reputation idea you put forward @AdrianHHH since I do feel that if I have asked a question the community is obviously still finding value in the I should continue to gain reputation for it, but the effective reputation solves the main issue I had where I didn't really prove that I should be trusted with the loaded shotgun of 'trusted user'.

Answer (score 7):

> So my basic question is - should residual income from a question stop after a time period?

No. If your old posts are still getting upvotes it should most likely mean that they are still helping people even today! So you should still reap the reward for the help you have given. It's well known on Stack Overflow that when you post a question or answer, that you're not only helping that specific questioner or yourself, but helping anyone else with a similar problem now and in the future.

> What i'm concerned about is that pretty soon i'll have access to the moderation tools - when I'm no longer putting in the effort to earn the privilege. While i'm not planning on abusing them obviously what is to stop another user in the same boat doing the same thing?

Even though you may not have been putting a lot of effort into the site recently, you have at one point. So once you get enough reputation you deserve the privileges that come with it. It's very rare for users to get to 20k on a few good posts.. but you have over 700! So definitely you've helped out the site a lot.

A user could abuse privileges, but there are many people that will eventually notice any reoccurring abuse and then the user would likely get suspended for a long time if appropriate. And any reversals to their negative actions could be figured out at that time as well.

Comment: The internet fosters many extremely dedicated trolls that will spend years of their lives gaining trust, and then when your butt cheeks least expects it, BAM! The inner demon is unveiled!